# Trying to use the pointplot command on Maple

Tags: maple

I'm trying to plot the points (n, a(n)) from n=1 to n=20, but Maple's just telling me what I want to plot, without actually plotting it. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try pointplot({seq([n,a(n)],n=1..20)});

Comment: You, my friend, are a lifesaver! One more thing: I'm trying to use Maple to find the smallest $N$ such that $|a_n--2|<\frac{1}{500}$. But when I try to use the solve command, it says 'Warning, solutions may have been lost). Any ideas?

Comment: Using fsolve produces a result if that's a help.

Comment: Tried that. I ran: fsolve(abs(a(n)+2)<1/500, n), but, alas, another error.

Comment: Try it so fsolve(abs(a(n)+2)-1/500), then you know the value when it's equal to $\frac{1}{500}$. From there you could deduce when it is less.

Comment: I've just done that and it's just repeating the same thing back to me in blue.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLzou.png

Comment: I got exactly what you got. Thanks. But, then, if I think about it, how can 1 (the ceiling value of 0.091...) be the least value of $N$ such that $|a_n+2|<\frac{1}{500}$. Looking at your graph, I see it's clear that $a_1$ (whose value is just over 2) is nowhere near the limit of $-2$, never mean to within $\frac{1}{500}$ of it! Could you elaborate...

Comment: If you're looking for discrete values of $n$ you could run a loop to find the first $n$ s.t. $|a_n+2|<\frac{1}{500}$; e.g. http://i.stack.imgur.com/588FV.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax worked for me, which produces the graph shown.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to use Maple to find the smallest N such that $|a_n−−2|<\frac{1}{500}$?